# Check if a variable is Saturday or Sunday

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a script to work that check if $acdate` is a Saturday or a Sunday, if it is it should alter the current class with a new one. But I don't get it to work for some reason and i have tried different methods, search for possible answers to get it to work but in the end i had to try you guys to see if you have a possible solution to the problem
the row caseclosure returns a value from 0-9 if you was wondering this is my code

```
<?php
$acdate = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tccrequest))
{
    $acdate = date('d-m-Y',time() + 86400 * $row['autoclosure']);
    if($row['ac update']!=1){
        if ($acdate <= date('d-m-Y')){
            $warning= "warning2";
        }
        else if ($acdate == date('d-m-Y')+1){
            $warning= "nextday";
        }
        else if ($acdate == strtotime('this Saturday')){
            $warning= "warning2";
        }
        else if ($acdate == strtotime('this Sunday')){
            $warning= "warning2";
        }
        else{
            $warning="";
            $disable = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
        }
    }else{
            $warning="updated";
            //$disable = "disabled=\"disabled\"";           
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime('this Saturday')` will return a Unix timestamp that corresponds on the Sunday in the current week. But your `$acdate` variable is a date string and hence the comparison using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) will never work. You'll have to convert the date into a timestamp before doing the comparison:

Change:

```
$acdate = date('d-m-Y',time() + 86400 * $row['autoclosure']);
```

to:

```
$acdate = time() + 86400 * $row['autoclosure'];
```

But in case you're trying to check if the date is a Sunday (regardless of the week it falls on), you can simply use the `l` format (lower-case L)`:

```
$acdateTS = strtotime($acdate);
if(date('l', $acdateTS) == 'Sunday') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to check with the date function if the $acdate = a saturday or a sunday. This because i use $acdate = date('d-m-Y',time() + 86400 * $row['autoclosure']); to write out the Todays date + $row['autoclosure'] in a field so it looks like 10-08-2013 i dont need to use strtotime if there is a nice way to get date() to check if $acdate is on a saturday or a sunday.

Comment: @user2955523: In that case, use a different variable for storing the timestamp.

Comment: I was able to solve it with this little code Thanks for all the help.
   else if (date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==6 or date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==0){
    $warning= "warning2";
   }

Comment: @user2955523: That's another way of doing it. It's exactly the same as `else if (date('l', strtotime($acdate))== 'Saturday' or date('l', strtotime($acdate))== 'Sunday'){ $warning= "warning2"; }` -- I think this is more readable, but you're free to use the one that suits *your* needs :)

Comment: Only thing im struggling with now is that it marks all sats and suns. I just want the next inline and the ones comming after should not be marked until it's a new week. And ofc i will always mark correct answer or part of a solution.

Comment: @user2955523: That should be [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$Datetime_acdate  = strtotime(acdate);

//will return string 'Sat' or 'Sun' or 'Mon' etc 
$DayofWeek = date('D', $Datetime_acdate );

if ($DayofWeek == 'Sat' or $DayofWeek == 'Sun'){
 //do something.
}
```

You should have the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function page on php.net on speeddial!!